# Extracting data from file to populate database with bash script

Tags: database, bash, awk, sed, sqlite

I have a dataset of many files. Each file contains many reviews of the type separated by a blank line:

```
<Author>bigBob
<Content>definitely above average! we had a really nice stay there last year when I and...USUALLY OVER MANY LINES
<Date>Jan 2, 2009
<img src="http://cdn.tripadvisor.com/img2/new.gif" alt="New"/>
<No. Reader>-1
<No. Helpful>-1
<Overall>4
<Value>4
<Rooms>4
<Location>4
<Cleanliness>5
<Check in / front desk>4
<Service>3
<Business service>4

<Author>rickMN... next review goes on
```

For every review I need to extract the data after the tag and put it in something like this (which I plan write to a .sql file so when I do ".read" it will populate my database):

```
INSERT INTO [HotelReviews] ([Author], [Content], [Date], [Image], [No_Reader], [No_Helpful], [Overall], [Value], [Rooms], [Location], [Cleanliness], [Check_In], [Service], [Business_Service]) VALUES ('bigBob', 'definitely above...', ...)
```

My question is how can I extract the data after each tag and put it in an insert statement using bash?

**EDIT**
Text after `<Content>` tag is usually a paragraph with a number of lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right approach for what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NF {
    if ( match($0,/^<img\s+src="([^"]+)/,a) ) {
        name="Image"
        value=a[1]
    }
    else if ( match($0,/^<([^>"]+)>(.*)/,a) )  {
        name=a[1]
        value=a[2]
        sub(/ \/.*|\./,"",name)
        gsub(/ /,"_",name)
    }

    names[++numNames] = name
    values[numNames] = value
    next
}

{ prt() }
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    printf "INSERT INTO [HotelReviews] ("

    for (nameNr=1; nameNr<=numNames; nameNr++) {
        printf " [%s]", names[nameNr]
    }

    printf ") VALUES ("

    for (nameNr=1; nameNr<=numNames; nameNr++) {
        printf " \047%s\047", values[nameNr]
    }

    print ""

    numNames = 0
    delete names
    delete values
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
INSERT INTO [HotelReviews] ( [Author] [Content] [Date] [Image] [No_Reader] [No_Helpful] [Overall] [Value] [Rooms] [Location] [Cleanliness] [Check_in] [Service] [Business_service]) VALUES ( 'bigBob' 'definitely above average! we had a really nice stay there last year when I and...USUALLY OVER MANY LINES' 'Jan 2, 2009' 'http://cdn.tripadvisor.com/img2/new.gif' '-1' '-1' '4' '4' '4' '4' '5' '4' '3' '4'
INSERT INTO [HotelReviews] ( [Author]) VALUES ( 'rickMN... next review goes on'
```

The above uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match(). Massage to get the precise formatting/output you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, there is a bug in the code. I think it's connected with the <img..> line and results in a duplicate ([Date] x 2). I'd be extremely grateful if you could help me resolve the issue (I'm not that familiar with regular expressions). Thank you again!

Comment: I'm going to use the approach you suggested, it was pretty much what I was thinking of doing but I didn't know how to do it. Please help me with the problem and thank you once again.

Comment: OK I tweaked the img regexp to fix that problem and tidied up the code slightly.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ ^\<Author\>(.*) ]] && Author="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  [[ $line =~ ^\<Content\>(.*) ]] && Content="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

  # capture lines not starting with < and append to variable Content
  [[ $line =~ ^[^\<] ]] && Content+="$line"

  # match an empty line
  [[ $line =~ ^$ ]] && echo "${Author}, ${Content}"
done < file
```

Output with your file:

```
bigBob, definitely above average! we had a really nice stay there last year when I and ...
```

---

> `=~`: match to a regex (string left, regex right without quotes)
>
> `^`: match start of line
>
> `\<` or `\>`: match `<` or `>`
>
> `.*`: here match rest of line
>
> `(.*)`: capture rest of line to first element of array `BASH_REMATCH`

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)